# 90 degrees rotated MIFA 2.4GHz Antenna reference design?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, pcb-antenna

[NXP offers a reference design](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/nxp/application-notes/AN11994.pdf) of a MIFA antenna for the 2.4 GHz BT LE frequencies. On page 4 of the PDF the design is shown:

[image: NXP reference design (c) NXP as per above PDF/document]

For my application this reference design is too wide; does anyone know of an existing reference design that offers a 90 degree rotated reference design (about as below, and yes, I know the traces are not connected ;). I would assume that I cannot simply add another 90 degree angle right at the beginning of the antenna and not suffer dire RF consequences.

[image: 90 degrees rotated MIFA antenna design "as it should be" for my application]

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a ground plane and some distance between the antenna and that ground plane. If you change anything in that respect, you've **changed the design**.

That doesn't mean that the antenna will stop working, it will work but it might be less efficient (less power is transmitted / received) and more power reflects back into the amplifier driving the antenna. So **performance** is expected to degrade.

If you're fine with that then you can still do "whatever" you like. Some cheap RF modules from China have antenna designs that look like little thought/design has gone into them. But these still work just don't expect the maximum performance (range) from them.

So in the end it is **your choice**, stick exactly to the NXP design and you know what you will get. Or change it to your needs and your results may vary.

Have you considered using a "chip antenna", these might give you more flexibility regarding the ground plane.

Comment: Thank you for, mostly, confirming what I was fearing to hear... I have actually thought about chip antennas (antennae?), yet the sheer number of choices available turned me away from this. Any recommendations when money is of an issue?

Comment: Product recommendations are Off topic here, I would not know what to recommend anyway. A pointer in the right direction would be to see what cheap "Chinese" modules use as these always use the cheapest components. Some ESP-07 modules use a "Rainsun" antenna: http://www.rainsun.com/en/2-4ghz-5ghz-wifi-bluetooth-zigbee-antenna/